# Load external assemblies into new app domain and call a method of "base class"

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, remoting

I'm new to remoting in .NET (which I believe this is related to).

Assume that main application references a class library **A** which contains an abstract class with an abstract method.

Now, assume that we create an entire new project **B** and reference the same DLL **A**, make a new class that inherits the abstract class and implements the method.

Is it possible to load this new assembly into a new appdomain in the main application and create an instance only knowing the base class type?

Or is there a better way? I'm thinking of some sort of plugin system here.

**Edit:** For reflection, we can find types that inherit the base class, and then use (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(ParentType); without having to know *ParentType*.

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to do - "create an instance only knowing the base class type" - how would code know what to create? It would be much easier to answer if you show what you already tried and where you got stuck (as there are plenty of "create class in another app domain" questions, so I'm sure you already read a lot of them)

Comment: What do you mean by "create an instance only knowing the base class type?" You need to know the type of instance that you are creating - you could _inspect_ all types in B and see if any extend "A", but what if there are multiple?

Comment: In other words, there's no built-in function to "create an instance of whatever type from B extends type T"

Comment: I edited the question. What I'm thinking of is similairly to Activator.CreateInstance. Is this possible in an external assembly as well in a different app domain?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774319/5114784) is an older answer of mine to a related question. Just like @user1624411, I used an interface instead of an abstract class. And the key is the `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`, which is your `Activator.CreateInstance` when using remoting. It also helps you from polluting the main domain with the loaded assemblies, which can be unloaded by `AppDomain.Unload`

Comment: Please note though that creating app domains (and thus whole remoting) is not supported in .NET Core. So if this is a new project consider to follow the [new recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support). [Here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/f7bd13a0151e96ede796ae00dc5575d81395143a/KGySoft.Drawing.ImagingTools/Model/InstallationInfo.cs#L164) is an example that works both in .NET Framework and .NET Core 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.
This prints 2147483647 from an external assembly that has a type derived from IPlugin.
IPlugin is defined inside your main domain:

```
var asy = Assembly.LoadFrom("yourChildAssembly.dll");

List<Type> availablePlugIns = asy.GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();

var myPluginType = availablePlugIns.FirstOrDefault();

if (myPluginType != null)
{
   IPlugin pluginInstance = (IPlugin)System.Activator.CreateInstance(myPluginType); 
   pluginInstance.MyPluginMethod();
}
```

Sample types used:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    int MyPluginMethod();
}

public class MyPluginClass : IPlugin
{
    public int MyPluginMethod()
    {
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

This example is just a quick & dirty solution with limits like your class should have a parameter less constructor to be instantiated. But you can use it as a starting point.

EDIT: I used and interface but it works also with abstract classes

Comment: This loads the plugin assembly in the main `AppDomain`

Comment: Yes it does. It was just to show how he can obtain a plugin-like system. If he follows my example and your recommendation about AppDomain, he will find a solution.